# How is the scale calculated out of width= \textwidth?

Tags: graphics, callout

I'm using the callouts package for rescaling images after putting some text and markers in it.

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\begin{annotate}{\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{./Bilder/testcenter_main_gui}}{0.8}
    %\callout{X-Start, Y-Start}{Text}{X-Ende, Y-Ende}
    %\helpgrid
    \draw [thick, \arcol] (-6.775,3.85) rectangle (-6.45, 4.2);
    \callout{-6, 0}{Testbundle laden}{-6.6125,3.85}

    \draw [thick, \arcol] (-6.37,3.85) rectangle (-6.05, 4.2);
    \callout{-4.8, 1}{Testplan laden}{-6.21,3.85}


\end{annotate}
\caption[Screenshot Hauptfenster Testcenter 2]{Hauptfenster Testcenter 2}
\label{fig:testcenter_main_gui}
\end{figure}
```

results in (don't mind the text, i wanted to give you the whole page)
[image]

i change the scaling to `width=0.4\textwidth` and the paramter of the callouts environment to `0,4`.

It gives me this:
[image]

I know the the annotate environment wants the scaling factor of the image to keep the proportions. I want to rescale using `\textwidth`.

How can i calculate the scaling ouf of `width=\textwidth` or `width=0.4\textwidth`?

Comment: I don't get it. You seem to use the package properly, and it seems to give the intended result. Could you explain what you want to do, or what is wrong with what you currently have?

Comment: I rechecked the documentation. The third parameter of the annotate environment wants the coefficient for width. I thought i wants the scale factor, thats why i wanted to calculate the scale factor out of `0.4\textwidth`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The annotate environment wants the coefficient of `width=0.4\textwidth`, so it wants `0.4`. My example didn't have errors in it.